# Outlook addin: Receive events in addin code (js files)

Tags: events, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an add in for Outlook 365 (2 buttons: 1 action and 1 task pane), and I have some doubts:

1. Is it possible to receive an Outlook event in my addin (js code) when an appointment is changed? For example if I change manually an appointment duration.
2. When I remove an event in the Outlook, is it possible to receive an event somehow before the event is removed?

Thanks,
Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, for your example you can use an [AppointmentTimeChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.eventtype?view=word-js-preview#fields) event that triggers when any date or time of the selected appointment or series is changed in Outlook.
2. Currently receiving an event before an event is removed is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. As I can see, there is no event for a subject change, correct? And, of course, my addin task pane must be open to get the event, correct?

Comment: There is no event for a subject change. Feel free to add this request to our user-voice page as well. Yes, you are correct, the add-in taskpane must be open to receive events.